# Drawing pixel circle of given area

Tags: algorithm, draw, bit, dithering

I have some area X by Y pixels and I need to fill it up pixel by pixel. The problem is that at any given moment the drawn shape should be as round as possible.

I think that this algorithm is subset of Ordered Dithering, when converting grayscale images to one-bit, but I could not find any references nor could I figure it out myself.

I am aware of Bresenham's Circle, but it is used to draw circle of certain radius not area.

I created animation of all filling percents for 10 by 10 pixel grid. As full area is 10x10=100px, then each frame is exactly 1% inc.

[image: pixel animation]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bresenham concentric circles leaving empty pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201907/bresenham-concentric-circles-leaving-empty-pixels)

Comment: So roughly speaking the result would be the rectangle area being filled up by the an increasing size disk centered in the middle of the area?

Comment: Does it have to start in the centre? Can you show what you consider the roundest filling if, say X=3Y and the area is 25%, 50% and 90% full please?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use Dijkstra's algorithm to find pixels in order of increasing distance from the center.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with dithering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filled disk has the equation

```
(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)² ≤ C.
```

When you increase `C`, the number of points that satisfies the equation increases, but because of symmetry it increases in bursts.

To obtain the desired filling effect, you can compute `(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)²` for every pixel, sort on this value, and let the pixels appear one by one (or in a single go if you know the desired number of pixels).

You can break ties in different ways:

- keep the original order as when you computed the pixels, by using a stable sort;
- shuffle the runs of equal values;
- slightly alter the center coordinates so that there are no ties.

---

Filling with the de-centering trick.

Values:

[image]

Order:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that is exactly what I have been looking for.